# How does shield work in loadout?

Tags: loadout

I would like to know how the shield in loadout works.

How much damage is blocked by it?

Does it regenerate by picking up health packs or over time or both?

Is there a way to counter it directly? Like emp grenades or something?

Comment: I don't actually have the shield (I think it's stupid and overpowered), but I do know that tesla weaponry is supposedly good for taking them down.  Don't know any hard values though.

Comment: I can add that one hit with anything tesla will instantly deplete the shield. Its capacity is something around 25-50% of your life, and it seems to recover automatically after you've gone on for a while without taking damage. I'm not completely certain, though, and I can't easily test it at the moment.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann i mainly use tesla at the moment and it seems to me that 1 hit does not remove the shield completely. i will watch more closely to confirm your statement. and yeah it would be great if the testmode(in the weaponcrafting section) would consist of enemy with shield so i could test it

Comment: @Wandang I just got a shield in weapon testing for some reason! You're right: one hit with a tesla weapon does not necessarily deplete the shield instantly, but it has a huge damage bonus. Something like 500% at least. Shield's HP is about 50% of your max, it recharges almost instantly after 9 or 10 seconds of taking no damage. Picking up medkits or ammo boxes doesn't affect it in any way. Still untested: juice and healing guns.

Comment: @Pvt.Grichmann nice findings. You should make an answer out of that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some preliminary testing results show that the shield essentially grants you 50% extra health. This extra 50% functions just like your regular health, with the following exceptions.

- It takes significantly (500% by my estimate) more damage from tesla weapons. That means a lot of tesla weapons will take the shield down with just one hit.
- It restores itself to full almost instantly after 9 seconds during which you take no damage. This is the only way to recharge the shield. Healing weapons, health pick-ups or ammo caches will do nothing to it.